# Finding functions $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ for which $\sum_{x\in\Bbb{R}}f(x)$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, nonstandard-analysis

A while ago, a friend asked me "for which functions $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ does the sum $\sum_{x\in\Bbb{R}}f(x)$ converge?", and a few days ago I completed a sketch of a proof that the sum converges iff there exists a countable set $X\subset\Bbb{R}$ (hereafter, '$X$') such that...

$$(1)\qquad\sum_{x\in X} f(x)\in\Bbb{R}$$

...and...

$$(2)\qquad\sum_{x\in X^\complement} f(x)=0$$

(Note: the sole discrepancy between this and the answer provided by others is that I have not made the assertion that $\sum_{x\in X^\complement}f(x)=0\iff\forall x\in X^\complement.f(x)=0$)

Of course, this isn't very informative; what would an example of such a function even be?

To be a little bit more concrete, I considered two cases which, far as I can tell, exhaust the possibilities for such functions.

The first case consists of functions which evaluate to $0$ for all points outside of a countable subset of the domain, for example, suppose $X=\Bbb{N}$...

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{x^2}&x\in\Bbb{N}\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

...for which...

$$\sum_{x\in\mathbb{R}}f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

Such functions trivially satisfy $(2)$, because for all $x$ in the complement of $X$, $f(x)=0$.

The second potential case consists of functions whose sum over $X$ likewise converges, but which are not necessarily $0$ for all points in $X^\complement$.

Now, when I first wrote this question, I had used a nonstandard interpretation of the integral to show that cancellation of partial sums is possible. However, as it has been pointed out to me, the same result is not readily obtained using only the familiar tools of real analysis. As an alternative to nonstandard methods, I propose the following:

i. If there exists a countable set $X\subset \Bbb{R}$ such that $\sum_{x\in X}f(x)\in\Bbb{R}$ and $\forall x\in X^\complement.f(x)=0$ then $\sum_{x\in\Bbb{R}}f(x)\in\Bbb{R}$ (the sum converges).

ii.   If there are disjoint sets $Y_1,Y_2\subset\Bbb{R}$ such that $Y_1\cup Y_2=X^\complement$ and $\sum_{x\in Y_1}f(x)=-\sum_{x\in Y_2}f(x)$ then $\sum_{x\in\Bbb{R}}f(x)\in\Bbb{R}$ (the sum converges).

The first of these is well known in real analysis, and provides an instance of conditions $(1)$ and $(2)$. This means that the convergence criteria I have established are at least inclusive of the usual ones.

In order to assess the second proposition using only standard methods, I would like to introduce a new function. For every real interval $p$, let $I(p)$ be the interval such that $\inf I(p)=0$, $\sup I(p)=\sup p-\inf p$, $\inf I(p)\in I(p)\iff \inf p\in p$, and $\sup I(p)\in I(p)\iff \sup p\in p$ - e.g. $I(x,y)=(0,y-x)$, $I[x,y)=[0,y-x)$, etc.

For every real interval $p$ let $I_p(x)=x-\inf p$.

Now, let $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ be disjoint intervals in $X^\complement$. If $I(Y_1)=I(Y_2)=Y_0$, then we may show that...

$$\sum_{x\in Y_1}f(x)+\sum_{x\in Y_2}f(x)=0$$

...if...

$$\forall x\in Y_0.(f\circ {I_{Y_1}}^{-1}+f\circ {I_{Y_2}}^{-1})(x)=0$$

For example, the sum...

$$\sum_{x\in\Bbb{R}}f(x)\quad:\quad f(x)=\begin{cases}1&x\in(-1,0]\\-1&x\in(0,1)\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

...converges to $1$ because for each $x\in I(-1,0)$, $(f\circ{I_{(-1,0)}}^{-1})(x))=1$ and $(f\circ{I_{(0,1)}}^{-1})(x))=-1$. Thus...

$$\sum_{x\in(-1,0)\cup(0,1)}f(x)=\sum_{x\in I(0,1)}f({I_{(-1,0)}}^{-1}(x))+f({I_{(0,1)}}^{-1}(x))=\sum_{x\in I(0,1)}0$$

...and...

$$\sum_{x\in\Bbb{R}}f(x)=\sum_{x\in\{0\}}f(x)+\sum_{x\in I(0,1)}f({I_{(-1,0)}}^{-1}(x))+f({I_{(0,1)}}^{-1}(x))+\sum_{x\in(-\infty,-1]\cup[1,\infty)}f(x)$$

$$=\sum_{x\in\{0\}}1+\sum_{x\in I(0,1)}0+\sum_{x\in(-\infty,-1]\cup[1,\infty)}0=1+0+0=1$$

Of course, what we *really* want is a non-piecewise function definable in $(\Bbb{R},+,\times,\cos,\ldots)$ [with iterates thereof].

Anyway, I'm at a loss as to how I should proceed beyond this point. Are there additional cases besides these? How should I go about looking for functions whose sum converges?

---

Note: It might seem unusual that there are 'neatly' expressible functions which are nowhere continuous, but this is indeed the case. Consider the function...

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\text{sgn}\left(\cos(nx)\right)}{k}$$

Edit: For the sake of evaluating the sum, it can be assumed that every subset of $\Bbb{R}$ inherits the natural ordering from $\Bbb{R}$. Additionally, it can be assumed that if $A\cup B=C$ for disjoint sets $A$ and $B$, then...

$$\sum_{x\in C}f(x)=\sum_{x\in A\cup B}f(x)=\sum_{x\in A}f(x)+\sum_{x\in B}f(x)$$

Edit: I made a mistake in the original post. I had said that the sum cannot converge if the function is differentiable. After going back over my work, I found that the sum over a particular *subset* does not converge if the function is differintiable everywhere in that subset *and* there is no point $x$ in the subset such that $f'(x)=0$. The converse does not hold.

Edit: it should be possible to extend the above method by considering the reverse order of an interval in addition to the standard ordering. I haven't quite figured out how to do this yet, though.

Edit: Added proof verification tag since I'm unsure of my attempt to frame cancellation in a purely standard context. I would appreciate it if someone could verify it for me.

Comment: This does not really make sense to me. Please define $\sum_{x \in \mathbb R} f(x)$

Comment: @AndresMejia The sum of the set $\{f(x)\mid x\in\Bbb{R}\}$, or, alternatively, $\sum f(\Bbb{R})$.

Comment: @AndresMejia under the correct usage of an infinitesimal $\varepsilon$, you can also have $\varepsilon\sum_{x\in\Bbb{R}}f(x)\approx\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\ dx$

Comment: how do you define $\sum_{n \in \mathbb N} -1^n/n$? Does it have to converge in the classical sense for all posible rearrangements? Why is $\sum_{x \in \mathbb R} f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)$?

Comment: The sum does not make sense unless you add some restrictions such as requiring $\sum_x |f(x)|$ to be bounded, or $f(x) \ge 0$.

Comment: As far as I see, the most reasonable way to define this is $$  \sum_{x\in \mathbb{R}} f(x) := \int_{\mathbb{R}} f \,\mathrm d\sigma, $$ i.e. the Lebesgue integral with respect to the counting measure $\sigma$.

Comment: @AndresMejia The equivalence of the sum assumes that $\Bbb{N}$ inherits the natural ordering from the reals. Then, because the function is $0$ everywhere *but* $\Bbb{N}$, the sum over the reals is the same as the sum over the naturals.

Comment: @MisterRiemann I'm not sure how this would work. The counting measure will be infinite, and the reals are uncountable. So even if we repeatedly take the Lebesgue integral over an infinite sequence of finite subsets, won't it still skip 'most' of the points in $\Bbb{R}$?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You might find [this](http://faculty.bard.edu/belk/math461/SumsOverSets.pdf) and [this](https://planetmath.org/UncountableSumsOfPositiveNumbers) interesting. Note that the definition used in the linked pdfs is precisely the Lebesgue integral with respect to the counting measure. (The second link also mentions this at the end of the article.) Also check out 4.15. in Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis, where he discusses this.

Comment: @MisterRiemann Okay, I see what you mean. The sum I am taking here is slightly different. I need to show that the *sum* of all but countably many values of $f(x)$ is $0$, which is a weaker condition. Without using infinitesimals, this works at least for order-isomorphic subsets $A$ and $B$ such that for all $a\in A$ there is a $b\in B$ such that $f(a)=-f(b)$. For example, you might have $f(x)=1$ if $x\in[-1,0)$, $f(0)=1$, and $f(x)=-1$ if $x\in(0,1]$, and $f(x)=0$ otherwise. Then $f(x):x\in[-1,0)$ and $f(x):x\in(0,1]$ cancel out by virtue of being reflections of each other.

Comment: But as others pointed out, the thing that you call *sum* is not even well-defined. You cannot define it in the same way as you define it for countably many terms, where you take the limit of partial sums. That's why I wrote that I believe that the Lebesgue integral is the (perhaps only) reasonable way to do it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93202/discussion-between-r-burton-and-misterriemann).

Comment: Generally speaking, a sum $\sum_{i\in I} x_i$ represents the limit (if it exists) of the *net* of finite partial sums. So the elements $x(S) := \sum_{i\in S} x_i$ form a net $(x(S))_{S\subseteq I}$ indexed by the finite subsets of $I$.

Answer (score 3):

A sum over an uncountable set, $\sum_{x \in A} f(x)$, can't converge unless there are only countably many $x \in A$ for which $f(x)\ne 0$.  Note that the notation $\sum_{x \in A}$ does not specify any order relation 
on $A$, so there is no possibility of some sort of "conditional convergence"
where  positive and negative values cancel out.

Comment: Correct. For any subset $A\subseteq\Bbb{R}$ the order is inherited from the natural ordering on the reals. To evaluate the sum in its entirety, take a family of sets $A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_n$ such that $A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_n=\Bbb{R}$. If you choose the right sets, then the cancellation (if it occurs) follows from symmetry (e.g. $\sum_{x\in A_1}f(x)=-\sum_{x\in A_2}f(x)$).

Comment: When I did it, I first showed that the integral over an interval is equal to the sum over the same interval multiplied by an infinitesimal. If you divide by the infinitesimal, you get a value which differs from the sum by, at most, an infinitesimal. Thus if the integrals over two intervals cancel out, there sum will also cancel out (up to an infinitesimal).

Comment: In standard mathematics, that makes no sense.  I don't know enough nonstandard analysis to be judge whether it can make sense there.

Comment: I'll try to reformulate the question using limits in place of infinitesimals, but it will take a while.

Comment: I've edited in my attempt at a purely standard interpretation. Also, I made a mistake regarding the differentiability requirement. In order for the sum to be convergent of an interval, the function cannot be differentiable with a nonzero derivative everywhere in that interval, but this does not need to be true of the function as a whole.

Comment: Also, it would *appear* that a continuous, everywhere differentiable function can have a convergent sum iff its sum converges to $0$, but I have yet to prove that this is the case. In such cases though, the integral must also converge to $0$. A nice example is $x/\exp(x^2)$